# HP Envy dv6 7206tx Boot loop after Factory reset

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot

Yesterday I used my recovery disk to factory reset my laptop. The installation process was successful. After all files and hp softwares are installed into laptop it restarts. From that point it stuck on boot looping. While boot loop it not shows hp logo instead it shows only windows 8 logo.

Once again tried to boot using recovery disc to confirm the files are copied inside the hard drive using backup files option. All windows 8 files are there inside the c drive (refer https://i.stack.imgur.com/cixHS.jpg).

Need help to boot into Windows 8.

**Product Name:** Hp envy dv6 7206tx

**Operating System:** Microsoft Windows 8 (64-bit)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried booting Windows into safe mode? If so, what were the results? Please [edit] your question to indicate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution [here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and-Software/TDC-SDV-FILE-option-on-startup/m-p/3283739). The problem is by default it starts to boot in to a corrupted OS partition which is called TDC-SDV (FILE). I have tried booting with a separate windows 8 bootable disc which has an option to choose the default operating system.

After login in to windows followed this simple steps to remove the corrupted operating system.

1. Go to windows, run command prompt and type "msconfig" at the command prompt.
2. In msconfig, click on the "boot" tab and remove the TDC SDV boot option, that is the failed Factory RESET operation
3. Reboot your laptop and you will not see any start up option, it should boot straight into Windows 8.

Thanks